# Error in building project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I can not create new project

Gives the following error

**Requested registry access is not allowed**

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution:

> !! CLOSE VISUAL STUDIO FIRST !!
>
> Step 1: Download subinacl.msi from the
>   link
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=23418
>   and install it.
>
> Step 2: Browse to C:/Program
>   Files/Windows Resource Kits/Tools/ and
>   create a file called vs2008fix.txt
>
> Step 3: Open the file you created, and
>   inside copy-paste:
>
> Code Block subinacl /subkeyreg
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.vbproj.9.0
>   /grant=administrators=f subinacl
>   /subkeyreg
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.vbproj.9.0
>   /grant=users=f subinacl /subkeyreg
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.vbproj.9.0
>   /grant=system=f
>
> Step 4: Save the file and change the
>   file extension to ".cmd". Then Start >
>   Run. Type "cmd" (without the quotes)
>   and type:
>
> cd C:/Program Files/Windows Resource
>   Kits/Tools
>
> Step 5: Press Enter. Then type:
>
> vs2008fix.cmd
>
> Step 6: Wait until it completes, then
>   start Visual Studio again. You should
>   be able to create project/files of any
>   type.

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/ac9f8e26-88c2-48fa-bdb5-59e3b4c9b8a5/

That's not the full solution, but follow the thread to get there.

Next time I would suggest doing a quick google search before posting on stackoverflow.